# Black tar like substance and streaks on attic roof and stains on chimney

Tags: roof, attic, chimney

I am looking into buying this house but saw a few things that concerned me.

The house got some strange tar like streaks on the inside of the roof. The chimney also has some black stains on the front, while the back of it looks completely fine. All the houses on the same block have this issues more or less.

Please could someone tell me what they might be and if it's difficult/ expensive to fix? Worth mentioning that a roof extension will be installed if we buy it.

[image: chimney].

[image: roof]

Comment: What did the prepurchase home inspection report have to say about these issues?

Comment: The black on the ply is almost certainly from where some bitumen-impregnated sheeting has been placed edge-on to the board, at some point before it was used. You can see  the straight line where it stood, and then scuff marks from where it has been dragged. 
It's absolutely nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: I agree with SiHa about the plywood, I can see no way that a tar-like sustance would have gone through plywood and form a perfectly straight line like this. Even if there was a line of small holes for it to go through it wouldn't look like this. For the chimney we need detail photos from a closer range to be sure, hard to tell like this. Is this side of the chimney the north side? Do all houses in the block have this on the same side regardless of the orientation of the house? (which would support the fungus explanation)

Answer (score 10):

I would suspect **fungus** on the chimney, possibly due to poor weatherproofing on top. If water is leaking and absorbing into the masonry it would support all manner of living things. You would need to improve the top covering and clean it with a bleach solution.

The plywood streaks seem like **adhesive** left from the manufacturing process to me. They aren't a concern.

Answer (score 6):

The black on the chimney is probably moss. And if other houses of the same age have it too, then its probably fine.

The black tar is probably tar or some sort of wax. It was probably transferred during construction.  It is not dripping, so it should be fine.

Comment: What sort of wax might it be and what hypothesis do you have for it getting there? That just seems odd. To be fair, presuming the black on the chimney is moss is rather bold, as well. Some citations for both statements would go a long way toward improving this answer.

Comment: @FreeMan Not taking sides, but I'd suggest that the spatial relationship between the stained chimney and stained plywood is crucial.